# Performing an async function before form post submission

Tags: forms, gatsby, netlify

**What I'm Trying To Do:**

On my site I've created a registration form that I'd like to perform two actions upon submission:

1. Subscribe the user to a MailChimp EDM list (using just the Name, Email fields).
2. Store the complete form in Netlify by performing a POST action (all fields, particularly their messages)

Here's my form:

```js
<form
  className={`contact-form ${submitError ? 'has-error' : ''}`}
  name={formName}
  method="POST"
  onSubmit={event => this.submitHandler(event)}
  action="/thank-you/"
  data-netlify="true"
  data-netlify-honeypot="bot-field"
>
   // Form fields
</form>
```

And here's my onSubmit handler:

```js
submitHandler = async (event) => {
  const {
    email,
    fieldValues,
    submitting,
  } = this.state;
  if (submitting) return false;
  this.setState({
    submitting: true,
    submitError: false,
  });
  const result = await addToMailchimp(email, fieldValues);
  if (result.result === 'success') {
    // Inconsequential, as success should result in redirection to the success page
    this.setState({
      submitting: false,
    });
  } else {
    event.preventDefault(); // this SHOULD stop form submit?
    this.setState({
      errorMessage: decodeEntities(result.msg),
      submitError: true,
      submitting: false,
    });
  }
}
```

**What's Happening Here:**

As you can see in the code snippets, in order to achieve this I am attempting to first asynchronously subscribe the user to MailChimp with the fields they have submitted, and if I don't get a success message I break the submit operation with `event.preventDefault();`.

As a bonus, this is also useful for preventing repeat registrations, as I'll get a message back from MailChimp if they're already on the subscribe list.

**The Issue:**

However, what happens in the wild is that the form submits and redirects to the success page (`/thank-you/`) regardless of whether the subscribe operation finishes, is successful or unsuccessful.

I've got about 50% of form submissions resulting in MailChimp subscriptions, and the other half not. When I'm testing this on my end, sometimes I see a blink of the subscribe success / failure message just before the page redirects to the success page (`/thank-you/`).

It's worthwhile noting `event.preventDefault();` works to break the form submit operation if it's executed at before the asynchronous / await function - so I'm guessing it's an issue with the time it takes to perform a subscribe operation.

Can anyone shed any light on what's happening here and a potential solution?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Can you `preventDefault` before the `await`, and then call `submit()` on the form after you get a success from the async call to `addToMailchimp`?

```
submitHandler = async (event) => {
  event.preventDefault()
  const form = e.target

  const {
    email,
    fieldValues,
    submitting,
  } = this.state;
  if (submitting) return false;
  this.setState({
    submitting: true,
    submitError: false,
  });
  const result = await addToMailchimp(email, fieldValues);
  if (result.result === 'success') {
    // Inconsequential, as success should result in redirection to the success page
    this.setState({
      submitting: false,
    });
    form.submit()
  } else {

    this.setState({
      errorMessage: decodeEntities(result.msg),
      submitError: true,
      submitting: false,
    });
  }
}
```

[working codesandbox example](https://codesandbox.io/s/gatsby-starter-default-9vn54)

Comment: Thanks so much @ksav, you're a bloody legend! It seems so simple, but this solution eluded me when I was trying to fix it myself. I noticed you use `event.persist()` at the start of your submitHandler in your codesandbox. Is there a reason why you omitted it in your answer here? Is it necessary?

Comment: Maybe in this example we no longer need it (because we save what we need from the event straight away). However, if find that you still need access to the event after your async code returns, i think you would need to persist it. I'm no expert so have a read of this https://reactjs.org/docs/events.html